# Linux Mint Cinnamon Lock-Up Debugging w/Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, javafx-8, linux-mint

I have a reproducible problem with the Mint Cinnamon desktop locking up when hitting a breakpoint debugging with Eclipse. When I say it's locking up, I mean mouse clicks are completely inoperable (even on the Mint panel), but the mouse cursor still moves. Keyboard is unresponsive, except for some OS-level shortcuts like Alt-Tab. Alt-Tab *looks* like it's working, but selecting another window doesn't actually focus or activate the window (only the Alt-Tab selector popup works). I can only recover using Ctrl-Alt-ESC to restart Cinnamon. Everything proceeds fine after that.

Debugging and breakpoints work fine everywhere else as far as I can tell except when the breakpoint is inside an anon inner class or lambda.

Public git repo with a fairly simple example project causing this: 
https://bitbucket.org/jfxexamples/eclipseminttest

Linux Mint 17.3 AND a totally new install of Mint 18 on a different PC - both behave the same
Eclipse Neon 4.6.0
Java 8 (1.8.0_92) - Oracle JDK (Using JavaFX)

Code below (you'll have to grab the project files to run it though):

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      try {
         BorderPane root = (BorderPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
         Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
         scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
         primaryStage.setScene(scene);
         primaryStage.show();
      } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }
}

package application;

import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;

public class SampleController {

   @FXML
   private TabPane tabPane;

   public void createTab() {

      Tab tab = new Tab("New tab");//Breakpoint here does NOT freeze desktop

//      tab.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
//         System.out.println("bleh");//Breakpoint here, freezes desktop
//      });
      tab.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<Event>(){
          @Override public void handle(Event e){
             System.out.println("bleh");//Breakpoint here, also freezes desktop
          }
      });

      tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);//Breakpoint here does NOT freeze desktop
      int index = tabPane.getTabs().size() - 1;
      tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(index);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Win10/IntellijCE/JDK1.8.0_92 there is no problem. Try using IntellijCE on Mint. If it works the problem is most likely with Cinnamon.

Cinnamon is on Github, so use their [Issue Tracker](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues) there to report the bug. 
Browsing the issues, there is even something maybe related to your issue: Check out https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/1084.

Comment: Good idea!  Reproduced with IntelliJCE on Mint.  So Eclipse is off the hook!  Still, could this be a JDK8 or JavaFX related issue?  That issue is pretty old so I'm thinking this might need to be a new Cinnamon issue.

Comment: I do not think that it is a Cinnamon related issue. I have exactly the same problem in Linux Mint 17.3 Mate, with JDK 1.8.0_101, Eclipse Neon and a JavaFX application.

Answer (score 1):

I have had exactly the same problem in Linux Mint 17.3 Mate, with JDK 1.8.0_101, Eclipse Neon and a JavaFX application.
When debugging the application, the system freezes completely and I have to kill the process manually.

It seems a [problem related with the X display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178642/debugging-an-swt-application-causes-all-gtk-application-to-freeze). It should work if you set, in the **VM arguments** of your application, the flag:

```
-Dsun.awt.disablegrab=true
```

At least that worked for me...

Comment: FYI, this avoids the hang, but also breaks drag and drop in the JavaFX app.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem on Linux. It is related to the [XGrabPointer](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/c.html) and [XGrabKeyboard](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XGrabKeyboard.html) API calls (see [X Pointer Grabbing)](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/pointer-grabbing.html). This API can be used by screensavers, so it is intended to make the keyboard and mouse unusable (apart from moving the mouse cursor).

During debugging, it is a problem. In the past, a workaround was to configure `AllowDeactivateGrabs`in xorg. That allowed to break the "grap" by a keyboard shortcut, by default <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>. Since it was possible to bypass screensavers, it was [disabled around 2012 because of its security implications](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=21652).

On a modern Linux system, you can enable enable grab break actions:

```
setxkbmap -option grab:break_actions
```

Now, you can trigger a grab break by executing:

```
xdotool key XF86Ungrab
```

Once your keyboard is frozen, you might be not able to run it, so during debugging, I am calling it every two seconds:

```
while :; do sleep 2 ; xdotool key XF86Ungrab ; done
```

Notes:

- `setxkbmap` is part of `xorg-setxkbmap`
- `xdotool` is part of `xdotool`
- While testing the setup, it is useful to have a ssh connection from another machine. Thus, if mouse and keyboard freeze up, you can always kill the process that grabbed the mouse and keyboard.